# How to matmul a 2d tensor with a 3d tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In `numpy` you can multiply a 2d array with a 3d array as below example:

```
>>> X = np.random.randn(3,5,4) # [3,5,4]
... W = np.random.randn(5,5) # [5,5]
... out = np.matmul(W, X) # [3,5,4]
```

from my understanding, `np.matmul()` takes `W` and broadcast it along the first dimension of `X`. But in `tensorflow` it is not allowed:

```
>>> _X = tf.constant(X)
... _W = tf.constant(W)
... _out = tf.matmul(_W, _X)

ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [5,5], [3,5,4].
```

So is there a equivalent for what `np.matmul()` does above in `tensorflow`? And what's the best practice in `tensorflow` for multiplying 2d tensor with 3d tensor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) to match the dimension of the matrix before multiplication. The automatic broadcast feature of numpy doesnt seem to be implemented in tensorflow. You have to do it manually.

`W_T = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(W,0),[3,1,1])`

This should do the trick

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = np.random.randn(3,4,5)
W = np.random.randn(5,5)

_X = tf.constant(X)
_W = tf.constant(W)
_W_t = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(_W,0),[3,1,1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.matmul(_X,_W_t)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but your code gives a `ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'Tile_3' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [5,5], [3].`

Comment: I forgot to expand dims. The 2D array must be converted 3D array before tiling.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tensordot` instead:

```
tf.transpose(tf.tensordot(_W, _X, axes=[[1],[1]]),[1,0,2])
```

Comment: Excellent! I saw `tf.tensordot` in the source code `tf.layers.Dense`. An elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

Following is from tensorflow XLA [broadcasting semantics](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting)

> The XLA language is as strict and explicit as possible, avoiding implicit and "magical" features. Such features may make some computations slightly easier to define, at the cost of more assumptions baked into user code that will be difficult to change in the long term.

So Tensorflow doesn't offers built in broadcasting feature.

However it does offer something that can reshape a tensor just like it was broadcasted. This operation is called [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)

Signature is as follow :

```
tf.tile(input, multiples, name=None)
```

> This operation creates a new tensor by
>   replicating input multiples times. The output tensor's i'th dimension
>   has input.dims(i) * multiples[i] elements, and the values of input are
>   replicated multiples[i] times along the 'i'th dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tf.einsum` to avoid tiling the tensor:

```py
tf.einsum("ab,ibc->iac", _W, _X)
```

A full example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Numpy-style matrix multiplication:
X = np.random.randn(3,5,4)
W = np.random.randn(5,5)
np_WX = np.matmul(W, X)

# TensorFlow-style multiplication:
_X = tf.constant(X)
_W = tf.constant(W)
_WX = tf.einsum("ab,ibc->iac", _W, _X)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf_WX = sess.run(_WX)

# Check that the results are the same:
print(np.allclose(np_WX, tf_WX))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll use keras backend `K.dot` and tensorflow `tf.transpose`.
first swap inner dim of 3 D tensor

```
X=tf.transpose(X,perm=[0,-1,1]) # X shape=[3,4,5]
```

now multiply like so

```
out=K.dot(X,W) # out shape=[3,4,5]
```

and now swap axes again

```
out = tf.transpose(out,perm=[0,-1,1]) # out shape=[3,5,4]
```

Above solution saves memory at little cost of time because you are not tiling `W`.