# Tensorflow: Add small number before division for numerical stability

Tags: tensorflow, scientific-notation, numerical-stability

In order to prevent divisions by zero in TensorFlow, I want to add a tiny number to my dividend. A quick search did not yield any results. In particular, I am interested in using the scientific notation, e.g.

```
a = b/(c+1e-05)
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Assuming a,b and c are tensors. The formula you have written will work as expected. 1e-5 will be broadcasted and added on the tensor c.

Comment: how can 1e-05 directly be specified as a tensor?

Comment: Tensorflow automatically typecasts `1e-5` to `tf.constant(1e-5)`. You can write it manually if you want.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind posting this as an answer to the question below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a`, `b` and `c` are tensors. The formula you have written will work as expected. `1e-5` will be broadcasted and added on the tensor `c`. Tensorflow automatically typecasts the `1e-5` to `tf.constant(1e-5)`.

Tensorflow however has some limitations with non-scalar broadcasts. Take a look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143808/how-to-matmul-a-2d-tensor-with-a-3d-tensor-in-tensorflow/51146877#51146877).